# If Else Argument Ignored

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, codeblocks

I'm writing a program to store Student IDs into an array of 20 PCs in 5 different labs. I pretty much got it, just when the program detects an ID that has already been used, it should print a statement and restart the program asking for a Student ID. However, when my program detects an used ID, it continues to ask for the lab then it prints the statement, then it continues to ask for the PC to book.

checkout(loop)

```
for(r=0;r<20;r++)
    {
        if(sId!=l1->pc[r] || sId!=l2->pc[r] || sId!=l3->pc[r] || sId!=l4->pc[r] || sId!=l5->pc[r])
        {
            printf("The Student ID '%i' has not made any booking\n", sId);
            return;
        }
    }
```

struct codes:

```
typedef struct
{
    int lId,pc[20],vunit;
}Openlab;
```

main

```
int main()
{
    Openlab lab1;
    Openlab lab2;
    Openlab lab3;
    Openlab lab4;
    Openlab lab5;

    int option;

    lab1.lId = 101;
    lab1.vunit = 20;
    lab1.pc[20];

    lab2.lId = 201;
    lab2.vunit = 20;
    lab2.pc[20];

    lab3.lId = 301;
    lab3.vunit = 20;
    lab3.pc[20];

    lab4.lId = 401;
    lab4.vunit = 20;
    lab4.pc[20];

    lab5.lId = 501;
    lab5.vunit = 20;
    lab5.pc[20];

    printf("***Welcome to OpenLab Booking Service***");
    while(option>3)
    {
        printf("\n\nPlease chose an option:");
        printf("\n[1]Check In");
        printf("\n[2]Check Out");
        printf("\n[0]Quit");
        printf("\n\nOption: ");
        scanf("%i", &option);

        if(option == 1)
        {
            check_in(&lab1,&lab2,&lab3,&lab4,&lab5);
            option = 4;
            printf("\nUnits Vacant Left in Lab 101: %i\n", lab1.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 201: %i\n", lab2.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 301: %i\n", lab3.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 401: %i\n", lab4.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 501: %i\n", lab5.vunit);
        }
        else if(option == 2)
        {
            check_out(&lab1,&lab2,&lab3,&lab4,&lab5);
            option = 4;
            printf("\nUnits Vacant Left in Lab 101: %i\n", lab1.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 201: %i\n", lab2.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 301: %i\n", lab3.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 401: %i\n", lab4.vunit);
            printf("Units Vacant Left in Lab 501: %i\n", lab5.vunit);
        }
        else if(option == 0)
        {
            printf("\n\nThanks for using the OpenLab Booking Service! See you again!\n\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

function:

```
void check_in(Openlab *l1, Openlab *l2, Openlab *l3, Openlab *l4, Openlab *l5)
{
    int sId,r,lab,comp;

    printf("Please enter your Student ID: ");
    scanf("%i", &sId);

    for(r=0;r<20;r++)
    {
        if(sId!=l1->pc[r] && sId!=l2->pc[r] && sId!=l3->pc[r] && sId!=l4->pc[r] && sId!=l5->pc[r])
        {
            while(lab!=l1->lId && lab!=l2->lId && lab!=l3->lId && lab!=l4->lId && lab!=l5->lId)
            {
                printf("Choose a Open Lab [101,201,301,401,501]: ");
                scanf("%i", &lab);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            printf("The Student ID '%i' has already been used to book a PC!\n", sId);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(l1->vunit!=0 && l2->vunit!=0 && l3->vunit!=0 && l4->vunit!=0 && l5->vunit!=0)
    {
        while(comp>19)
        {
            printf("Choose a PC [0-19]: ");
            scanf("%i", &comp);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\nNo vacant PC left Open Lab %i!\n\n", lab);
    }

    if(lab==l1->lId)
    {
        //printf("Booking for %i - Lab %i | PC %i ",sId,lab,comp);
        if(l1->vunit!=0)
        {
            l1->vunit--;
            l1->pc[comp] = sId;
        }
    }
    else if(lab==l2->lId)
    {
        //printf("Booking for %i - Lab %i | PC %i ",sId,lab,comp);
        l2->vunit--;
        l2->pc[comp] = sId;
    }
    else if(lab==l3->lId)
    {
        //printf("Booking for %i - Lab %i | PC %i ",sId,lab,comp);
        l3->vunit--;
        l3->pc[comp] = sId;
    }
    else if(lab==l4->lId)
    {
        //printf("Booking for %i - Lab %i | PC %i ",sId,lab,comp);
        l4->vunit--;
        l4->pc[comp] = sId;
    }
    else if(lab==l5->lId)
    {
        //printf("Booking for %i - Lab %i | PC %i ",sId,lab,comp);
        l5->vunit--;
        l5->pc[comp] = sId;
    }
}
```

check out:

```
void check_out(Openlab *l1, Openlab *l2, Openlab *l3, Openlab *l4, Openlab *l5)
{
    int sId,r;

    printf("Please Enter your Student ID: ");
    scanf("%i", &sId);

    for(r=0;r<20;r++)
    {
        if(sId==l1->pc[r])
        {
            l1->pc[r] = 0;
            l1->vunit++;
            printf("Removed");
            //return;
        }
        else if(sId==l2->pc[r])
        {
            l2->pc[r] = 0;
            l2->vunit++;
            printf("Removed");
            //return;
        }
        else if(sId==l3->pc[r])
        {
            l3->pc[r] = 0;
            l3->vunit++;
            printf("Removed");
            //return;
        }
        else if(sId==l4->pc[r])
        {
            l4->pc[r] = 0;
            l4->vunit++;
            printf("Removed");
            //return;
        }
        else if(sId==l5->pc[r])
        {
            l5->pc[r] = 0;
            l5->vunit++;
            printf("Removed");
            //return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case it may be best to use a switch statement

Comment: What this line is supposed to mean: `lab2.pc[20];` ? It is an *undefined behavior* by the way. You have five of these.

Comment: In the `main` function your `while` loop uses `option` before it is initialized. The value of an uninitialized local variable is *indeterminate* (and will seem random).

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Building on @Someprogrammerdude's observation, what you probably want there is a `do-while` loop in that it will always enter the loop the first time, and then it will use the conditional to see whether it should loop back again.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Its for the number of PC in each lab, I'm assigning 20 PC to each lab(1-5)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Got It!. Thanks for the advice, i changed the codes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changed it to a `do-while` loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the logic all backwards. The way you've got it currently, is it looping through all 20 slots and checking all 5 labs to see if a student is already assigned to one of them. If it isn't, then you ask what lab they're in and continue checking. You should wait until the loop has finished before asking about the lab.

Instead of what you've got, you should have it look to see if a student is assigned and if they are, print out the error message and `return` from the function since there's no point continuing.

```
for(r=0;r<20;r++)
{
    if(sId==l1->pc[r] || sId==l2->pc[r] || sId==l3->pc[r] || sId==l4->pc[r] || sId==l5->pc[r])
    {
        printf("The Student ID '%i' has already been used to book a PC!\n", sId);
        return;
    }
}
```

If the loop completes, then you can ask what lab to assign them. It's worth noting that you should assign a value to `lab` before you use it as it could hold any value, including a valid lab ID which would cause it to skip the `while` loop. Or alternative, you could make it a `do...while()` loop as you always want to ask the question at least once.

```
do
{
    printf("Choose a Open Lab [101,201,301,401,501]:\n");
    scanf("%i", &lab);
}
while(lab!=l1->lId && lab!=l2->lId && lab!=l3->lId && lab!=l4->lId && lab!=l5->lId);
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help, I got it now. So i gotta be careful with the for loop. Thanks again. Also sorry for the late response.

Comment: I seem to have a problem with the check_out function. I have edited the codes above, do have a look if you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. It'd be better to start a new question since your new problem is unrelated to the original question.